# Java enum : Refactoring switch statements 'constant expression required' compile error?

Tags: java

I have a class declaring constants for my app

```
public class GroupConstants {
    ..
    public static final int INTEGER_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int LONG_VALUE = 2;
    public static final int STRING_VALUE = 3;
    ..
}
```

In the code there is a set of switch statements

```
private static Object getValue(String stringValue, Parameter parameter) throws InvalidPatternException
{
    Object result=null;
    switch (parameter.getDataType())
    {
        case GroupConstants.STRING_VALUE: // String value
            result=stringValue;
        break;
        case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE: // Long value
        case GroupConstants.LONG_VALUE:
        case GroupConstants.BOOLEAN_VALUE:
        case GroupConstants.DATE_VALUE:
..
}
```

I want to refactor the int constant values to be represented by an enum

```
public enum DataType {

    UNKNOWN_VALUE(0,"unknown"),
    INTEGER_VALUE(1,"integer"),
    LONG_VALUE(2,"long"),
    STRING_VALUE(3,"string"),
    BOOLEAN_VALUE(4,"boolean"),
..
}
```

so my code might look like this

```
@Deprecated
public static final int INTEGER_VALUE = DataType.INTEGER_VALUE.getId();
```

and overtime i can change my switch statements. When i change the static final int reference to point to the enum all my switch statements break.

```
[javac] /home/assure/projects/tp/main/src/a/b/c/DDDDDManagerBean.java:1108: constant expression required
[javac]             case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE:
[javac]                                ^
[javac] /home/assure/projects/tp/main/src/a/b/c/ParameterComponent.java:203: constant expression required
[javac]         case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE:
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /home/assure/projects/tp/main/src/a/b/c/ParameterComponent.java:268: constant expression required
[javac]             case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE:
[javac]                                ^
[javac] /home/assure/projects/tp/main/src/a/b/c/ParameterComponent.java:316: constant expression required
[javac]             case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE:
[javac]                                ^
[javac] /home/assure/projects/tp/main/src/a/b/c/ParameterComponent.java:436: constant expression required
[javac]         case GroupConstants.INTEGER_VALUE:
```

I don't want to be forced to change all the switches yet, so its there a clean work around?

Comment: Isn't your GroupConstants the old way?  Should it not be case DataType.INTEGER_VALUE: that should be in the compiler error?

Comment: Based on what you've shows so far, I can't see what the problem is; this should work based on what I *assume* you're doing in e.g. `ParameterComponent`.  But then again, the error messages have nothing to do with the new `DataType` class, though, so perhaps I'm misinferring the code that's causing the compile errors.  Could you paste a little bit of the code that doesn't compile (e.g. the ParameterComponent class), and highlight where the error occurs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That won't work.  The problem is that the `getId()` call means that the constant's value expression is not a compile-time constant expression according to the JLS.  Refer to [JLS 15.28 Constant Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28) for the gory details, and you will see that method calls are not allowed in constant expressions.

I don't think there is any workaround, apart for a large-scale change to all of the switch statements.  But I wouldn't worry.  Your IDE should be able help you find and replaces all occurrences of the old constants.

**FOLLOWUP**

The following code from your comment won't work either:

```
private int INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER = DataType.INTEGER_VALUE.getId(); 
public static final int INTEGER_VALUE = INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER;
```

Firstly, `INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER` is not a "constant variable" according to the definition in [JLS 4.12.4 Final Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.4).  Therefore neither is `INTEGER_VALUE`.

Secondly, the initializer expression for a static cannot refer to `this`, and `INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER` is really another way of saying `this.INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER`.

Comment: Your correct - a nasty work around is : private int INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER = DataType.INTEGER_VALUE.getId();  public static final int INTEGER_VALUE = INTEGER_VALUE_HOLDER; But it defeats the purpose of the refactor.

Answer (score 16):

Java has native support of enums in switch statements. In your case you should say:

```
DataType type = ...;

switch (type) {
    case UNKNOWN_VALUE
        //do something
        break;
    case INTEGER_VALUE
        //do something
        break;
    case LONG_VALUE
        //do something
        break;
    case STRING_VALUE
        //do something
        break;
    case BOOLEAN_VALUE
        //do something
        break;
```

Comment: Your correct about using the Enum to drive the switch statement. In my case the DataType represents an Object type, so rather than refactoring the switch to use Enum's, I plan to create an interface and move the logic with in the case statements to the object, allowing be to remove the switch statements from the code.

Answer (score 9):

Try getting rid of the `GroupConstants.` prefix in your case statements. For reasons completely unclear to me, it doesn't accept the same constant if it's prefixed with class name.

So instead of

```
 case GroupConstants.STRING_VALUE:
```

please try:

```
 case STRING_VALUE:
```

You might need a static import to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

complementing AlexR's answer, converting a string to get an enum:

```
DataType type = Datatype.valueOf(enumName);

switch (type) {
case UNKNOWN_VALUE
    //do something
    break;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse IDE is simple ,in switch sentence CTRL + 1  and convert switch sentence - if-else sentence http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: What relevance is this? Enums are allowed in switch statements already.